# Hyperlink doesn't work properly with associated command

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, hyperlink

I have `Hyperlink` in a `Grid`. I bind command to hyperlink that Enables/Disables it. Then I disable it using the command. Then on its parent (`Grid`) I set `IsEnabled=False` property. After that I enable my Hyperlink with my command and enable Grid, but hyperlink doesn't activate!

Here is sample:

```
Command testCommand = new Command();

public MainWindow() {
  InitializeComponent();
  hl.Command = testCommand;
}

private void Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

  //Disable Hyperlink
  testCommand.Enabled = false;
  //Disable Grid
  grid.IsEnabled = false;
  //Enable Hyperlink
  testCommand.Enabled = true;
  //Enable Grid
  grid.IsEnabled = true;
  //hl.IsEnabled = true; //if uncomment this all will be work
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication25.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="172"
        Width="165">
  <StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
      <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink x:Name="hl">Test</Hyperlink>
      </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Start"
            Name="button1"
            Click="Start" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And register an ICommand:

```
public class Command : ICommand {
  private bool enabled;
  public bool Enabled {
    get {
      return enabled;
    }
    set {
      enabled = value;
      if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
  public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
    return Enabled;
  }
  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
  public void Execute(object parameter) { }
}
```

**Update:**

If Hyperlink is replaced with Button, it will be enabled even if its parent is disabled (grid.IsEnabled = false).

Comment: I don't see any command bindings setup to actually bind your testCommand's Execute and CanExecute implementations to the command itself. Did you just not include this part of your code? If you don't have command bindings setup, the control will never activate, regardless of any IsEnabled settings.

Comment: By overwriting the binding to the command in the `Start` button, your XAML never receives command notifications as @DanaCartwright points out.

Comment: I simplify my example. It's not due to `DataBinding`.

Answer (score 1):

Wow I got it
Here's what you are missing

```
 public class Command : ICommand
    {
        private bool enabled;
        public bool Enabled
        {
            get
            {
                return enabled;
            }
            set
            {
                enabled = value;
                //if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                //    CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return Enabled;
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter) { }
    }
```

The CanExecuteChanged delegates the command subscription to the CommandManager

Comment: This doesn't help, if I enable the Grid not in "Start" method (e.g. in other event handler)